# Aura Redirect Component Only if CustomerID is not Null

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller, conditional, if

I wrote code for an Aura Redirect Component but I'm having trouble getting it to redirect only if the CustomerId is not null. Here's my code.

Apex Controller

```
public with sharing class NetsuiteQuote {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static string getOpportunityUrl(String id){
        Opportunity opp = [SELECT Netsuite_Customer_ID__c, Netsuite_Employee_ID__c, X18_Character_Opp_ID__c, Netsuite_Opportunity_Stage__c, CloseDate   
                           FROM Opportunity WHERE Id=:id];
        if(opp.Netsuite_Customer_ID__c == null){
            opp.addError('Customer is not synchronized with NetSuite yet. Please try again in 5 minutes.');
            //string error= 'Customer is not synchronized with NetSuite yet. Please try again in 5 minutes.';
            return  'Customer is not synchronized with NetSuite yet. Please try again in 5 minutes.';
        }

        else if(opp.Netsuite_Customer_ID__c != null){
            string NSCustID= opp.Netsuite_Customer_ID__c ;
            string NSsalesRep= opp.Netsuite_Employee_ID__c;
            string SFOpportunity= opp.X18_Character_Opp_ID__c;
            decimal NSOpportunityStatus= opp.Netsuite_Opportunity_Stage__c;
            Date SFcloseDate= opp.CloseDate;

            string sURL='https://system.netsuite.com/app/site/hosting/scriptlet.nl';
            sURL +='?script=528&deploy=1&compid=3962188_SB2';
            sURL += '&action=new';
            sURL += '&customer=' + NSCustID;
            sURL += '&salesRep=' + NSsalesRep;
            sURL += '&sfdcOpportunity=' + SFOpportunity;
            sURL += '&sfdcOpportunityStatus=' + NSOpportunityStatus;
            sURL += '&closeDate=' + SFcloseDate;
            //alert('Customer is not synchronized with NetSuite yet. Please try again in 5 minutes.');        
            return sURL;
        }
        //acc.BillingStreet = acc.BillingStreet.replace(' ', '+');
        else return 'Opportunity not found.';
    }
}
```

Aura Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId" controller="NetsuiteQuote" >
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="opp" type="Opportunity" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.opp== 'Customer is not synchronized with NetSuite yet. Please try again in 5 minutes.'}">
        <p><lightning:formattedText value="{!v.opp}"/></p>
    </aura:if>
</aura:component>
```

Component Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var recordId = component.get("v.recordId");
        var action = component.get("c.getOpportunityUrl");
        action.setParams({
            "id" : recordId
        });
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState(); 
            if(state == "SUCCESS" && component.isValid()){
                console.log("success") ;
                
                var result = response.getReturnValue();
                component.set("v.opp", result);

                console.log(result);
                if(result == 'Customer is not synchronized with NetSuite yet. Please try again in 5 minutes.'){
                   console.error = 'Customer is not synchronized with NetSuite yet. Please try again in 5 minutes.'; 
                }
                else{
                    var urlRedirect = result;
                    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
                    urlEvent.setParams({
                        "url": urlRedirect
                    });
                    urlEvent.fire();
                    
                    // Close the action panel
                    var dismissActionPanel = $A.get("e.force:closeQuickAction");
                    dismissActionPanel.fire();
                }
            }else{
                console.error("fail:" + response.getError()[0].message); 
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning *String* from your apex method so you should check like this in Aura *Controller*

```
if(result == 'Customer is not synchronized with NetSuite yet. Please try again in 5 minutes.')
```

Also When checking for Empty in Apex you can do the following so that it can check for all possible scenario of field being empty

```
String.isBlank(opp.Netsuite_Customer_ID__c);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change from if(opp.Netsuite_Customer_ID__c ==' ') to if(opp.Netsuite_Customer_ID__c == null) and I had to modify my component to display the error and the issue was fixed. Thanks for your help.